# improve mysql query in large tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a query to get data between current time and INTERVAL 15 minutes

**Table calls have 39790720 items;**

```
SELECT src,unique,dstchannel,chan,calldate 
FROM calls 
WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW() 
   AND (dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT1/%' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT2%' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT3%' 
        OR dstchannel REGEXP '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT4%' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT5%' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT6%' 
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT7%'
   ) 
   AND lastdata NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%' 
LIMIT 39780720,39790720


Query 1 row in set (1 min 7.38 sec)

    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
    | calldate    | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
    | colum1      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum11     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | src         | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum12     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | chan        | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | dstchannel  | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum2      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum3      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum4      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
    | colum5      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
    | colum6      | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum7      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
    | colum8      | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum9      | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
    | colum10      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |                     |       |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

how to improve query ?

**UPDATE**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calls   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 39791545 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: That is a very general question, and I would advise you to 1) run EXPLAIN on that query and add the results to your question and 2) give info about indices on that table that may exist + the table DDL. Lastly, a word about the hardware you're running this query on. Maybe your server is just undersized memorywise, or has dog slow harddisks, two factors that are absolutely deadly for database work.

Comment: In my experience, switching to an INNODB table type can help, if it isn't already. Also, `calldate` should likely have a non-unique index, as should `dstchannel`.. the columns you use in `WHERE` clauses. Um.. I don't comprehend that LIMIT clause though.

Comment: %TEXT1% is reference for combination variable in my script but here dont write... im update my question

Comment: "Like '%...' " is just about the worst thing you can do to a query

Comment: But i need amm... for example LIKE '%SIP/phone%' only need contain %SIP/phone%' when value is SIP/phonexxx SIP/phonexxskshs

Comment: To be honest, despite them being correct. If you have a wildcard (%), you need it for functionality. So no point discussing that. What you can do, is mess around with the limit. Cause 39780720 can be a hell of a lot of data.

I would look at optimizing that.

Comment: I'll second @DuaneLortie in saying an index on `calldate` could help quite a bit. With all the `LIKE '%...`'s I doubt an index on `dstchannel` would help much; `LIKE`s with strings beginning with wildcards are not able to take advantage of indexing. _`REGEXP` isn't all that great for performance either, but merging all those `LIKE`s into a single `REGEXP` **might** help speed a little._

Answer (score 0):

Holy extreme query pessimization, Batman!

Your query looks like this:

```
SELECT src,unique,dstchannel,chan,calldate
  from calls
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
   AND (   dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT1/%'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT2%'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT3%'
        OR dstchannel REGEXP '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT4%'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT5%'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT6%'
        OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT7%') 
   AND lastdata NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%' 
 LIMIT 39780720,39790720
```

You can improve this query slightly by putting an index on `calldate`.  Your `calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()` clause will see some improvement from that.

But it will never be fast the way you have structured it.  Why not?

1. `dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT2%'` and similar clauses cannot, *ever*, exploit indexes.  Why not? Because they must search an entire column for a string, and cannot look just at the first characters of the column. Notice that `dstchannel LIKE 'TEXT2%'` *can* exploit an index with random access. It's an anchored search, starting at the beginning of the column.
2. `lastdata NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%'` has the same problem. But even if it were `lastdata NOT LIKE`TEXT8%` it would cause you problems, because every row needs to be examined. The server can't figure out how to access a range of data.
3. `OR` clauses are a disaster. They often cause MySQL to scan the same data multiple times.
4. `LIMIT 39780720,39790720` forces MySQL to romp through almost forty megarows in its result set discarding them. That burns MySQL server memory, processor time, and disk IO, just to discard it. Can you somehow use an `ORDER BY` clause in a clever way so you can retrieve the first rows of the result set rather than skipping them?

What can you do to fix this?  Your best bet is to rethink this whole `LIKE '%something%'` business.

If you can't do that, maybe you can try recasting your query like so. I assume you have a primary key on your `calls` table. I'll call it `id`.

```
SELECT a.src, a.unique, a.dstchannel, a.chan, a.calldate
  FROM a.calls
  JOIN (
          SELECT id FROM calls
           WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
             AND dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT1/%'
           UNION
          SELECT id FROM calls
           WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
             AND dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT2/%'
           UNION
          SELECT id FROM calls
           WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
             AND dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT3/%'
           UNION
                  etcetera.
           UNION
          SELECT id FROM calls
           WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
             AND dstchannel REGEXP '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-'
           UNION 
                  etcetera.
       ) b ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE lastdata NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%'
```

Then, create a compound index for your table on the columns `(calldate, dstchannel, id)`.  Then the MySQL query planner can use that index to find the appropriate `calldate` range, then scan the `dstchannel` values stored in the the index for matches, then extract the id values.  Then, it will turn around and use, in the `JOIN`, those `id` values to fetch precisely the data you need from the main table.

If you're working with call detail records, you really need to understand indexing. Read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Not _"all except one row"_. `LIMIT X, Y` gets up to Y rows, starting at offset X. Also, with the starting wildcards I doubt all those `UNION`s would be any better than his `OR` list; the main problem with `OR` lists is their disregard for indexes, which the starting wildcards prevent even the simpler UNIONed subqueries from taking advantage of.

Comment: Ooops, I missed the fact that the two numbers in LIMIT were large. thought they were the same number. Fixed. As far as the UNION stuff goes, the covering index I suggest should allow a tight index scan for each separate `LIKE '%stuff%'` hunt, but only on the fifteen-minute subset of the call detail records.  Tight scans of appropriate indexes save a lot of IO (disk) channel time over table scans.

Comment: Distance between X and Y doesn't matter, Y is a count specifier (though op maybe meant to only return 10k). But yeah, I am operating under the assumption MySQL will only do the OR conditions over the subset defined by the calldate condition; if the OR conditions end up mucking with that the UNION could be better.